# Why is my django-crispy AdminForm not able to resolve AdminSite url?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

## Setup

I defined an new admin url:

```
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path

class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):

     def get_urls(self):
         from django.urls import path
         urls = super().get_urls()
         urls += [
            path(
                "generate",
                admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view),
                name="generate",
            )
         ]
         return urls

     def my_view(self, request):
        print(request.data)
        return HttpResponse("Hello!")

admin_site = MyAdminSite()
```

The url is successfully registered:

```
print(admin_site.get_urls())
[ ..., ..., <URLPattern 'generate' [name='generate']>]   # <-- here!
```

Now in my `django-crispy-form`, I need to add a form action for multiple submit buttons. The library does not allow multiple form actions to be set, so I had to disable the form tag and add a new one manually:

```
class PromptForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()          # django-crispy-forms
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_tag = False        # <-- disable form_tag

        # Form layout 
        self.helper.layout = Layout(

            # Add new form_tag 
            HTML("""<form action="{% url 'admin:generate' %}"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="generate"></form>"""),
        )
```

## Issue

Both `{% url 'generate' %}` and  `{% url 'admin:generate' %}` are unable to reverse match the new url:

```
`django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'generate' not found. 'generate' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

## Update

I've registered the AdminSite to the admin like so:
`admin.site = MyAdminSite()`
But now, the url is resolved but the page 404

Comment: Both {% url 'generate' %} and {% url 'admin:generate' %} are unable to reverse match the url. Clear, you worknot correct with namespaces

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Solution

Add a custom action to the url `/admin/.../change` by overriding `django.contrib.admin.options.ModelAdmin._changeform_view`:

```
from django.contrib import admin 

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 

    def _changeform_view(self, request, object_id, form_url, extra_context):

        if '<your-action>' in request: 
            # 1. check permissions
            # 2. do your thing 
            print(request)
        
        return super()._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

You can now add simple sumbit button to your form with your custom action:

```
<input type="submit" name="<your-action>" value="<button-title>">
```

### Advantage

- Zero javascript.
- Authentication protected.
- All stock admin actions will work with your form (add, save and continue, ...)

Comment: You are not solve the problem and add a new one. Resolve problem is clear, you work don't correct with namespaces. And you dont need the action url. You can add action itself to MyModelAdmin, instead of override privat method of ModelAdmin class

Comment: If you know better than post the answer.